# Python matplotlib: animate Line2d

Tags: python, matplotlib, jquery-animate

I want to animate circles and lines with matplotlib. I was able to to this with circles, but not with lines. The following code works for the circles(without the line parts). With the line-parts, matplotlib just opens a white window.

```
#imports...
#create figure called ax

mypatch[0] = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.75, fc='y')
mypatch[1] = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.75, fc='y')
#... more patches

myline[0] = lin.Line2D([0,0],[0,0],color='b')
myline[1] = lin.Line2D([0,0],[0,0],color='b')
#... more lines

def init():
    ax.add_patch(mypatch[0])
    ax.add_patch(mypatch[1])
    #...
    ax.add_line(myline[0])
    ax.add_line(myline[1])
    #...
    return mypatch, myline

def animate(i):
    #trajectory of mypatch and myline
    return mypatch, myline

anim = anmiation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,...)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The lines go from (0,0) to (0,0) so there's nothing to plot.

Something like the following will make lines show up in your example:

```
myline[0] = Line2D([0,1],[0,1],color='b')
myline[1] = Line2D([0,1],[0,0.8],color='b')
```